# Plot eigen Vector e1 & e2 in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

How to be able plot eigen vector in Matlab an make it sure have the exact position as a new axes of our data??

here is my code for PCA

```
  a= randn(100,3); 
  b=mean(a);
  c=cov(a); 


  [vec,val] = eigs(c);
  e1=vec(:,1); 
  e2=vec(:,2); 


  plot3(a(:,1),a(:,2),a(:,3),'ro');
  hold on
  %% Here is the Problem begins
  plot(e1,'k--');
  plot(e2,'k--');
```

Here is the output that I got
[image]

That two lines represent the e1&e2.
How to plot the e1 & e2 properly???

Comment: Do you have a special reason for using `eigs` instead of `eig`? If not, then you should stick to `eig`. FYI.

Comment: either eig or eigs give me the same wrong result!! not different

Comment: I though that your problem was plotting?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the output  from `eig` to directly plot all three eigenvectors (or a subset):

```
a = randn(100,3); 
b = mean(a);
c = cov(a); 

[vec,val] = eig(c);

plot3(a(:,1),a(:,2),a(:,3),'ro');
hold on

z = zeros(1,3);
% plot3([z(1:2);vec(1,1:2)],[z(1:2);vec(2,1:2)],[z(1:2);vec(3,1:2)],'k')
plot3([z;vec(1,:)],[z;vec(2,:)],[z;vec(3,:)],'k')
axis equal
grid on
```

And if you want the scaled eigenvectors:

```
sc_vec = vec*val;
z = zeros(1,3);
plot3([z;sc_vec(1,:)],[z;sc_vec(2,:)],[z;sc_vec(3,:)],'b')
```

Another option is to use [`quiver3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver3.html) to get lines with arrowheads:

```
scale = 1;
z = zeros(1,3);
quiver3(z,z,z,vec(1,:),vec(2,:),vec(3,:),scale,'g')
```

Just don't expect the arrows to always look perfect, because Matlab isn't particularly good at this sort of thing.

Note that `eig` may return the eigenvalues and -vectors in a different order than `eigs`, but it is the function that you should be using. `eigs` is a specialized function that solved the eigenproblem in a different way and is much less efficient.

Comment: So, eig is much better than eigs??What this is mean "plot3([z;vec(1,:)]"

Comment: Hii, I tried ur code.. There s no different of the eigenvecors before scalling and after scalling

Comment: @user3303896: `[z;vec(1,:)]` is just a matrix containing the x-coordinates of the lines to plot (similar for the y- and z-). The first row is all zeros because the vectors originate at the origin (the mean of `randn`) and the second row is the x-coordinates of all three eigenvectors returned by `eig`.  And yes, `eig` is better than `eigs` unless you're trying to solve special types of problems.

Comment: @user3303896: You didn't see a difference because the vectors are scaled by the eigenvalues in this case and all of the eigenvalues are likely fairly close to one. There is a difference, but it's not large. Scaling by the eigenvalues gives some more physical meaning by showing *magnitude*, but you can also just scale by some large constant as the other answers show if you're simply interested in the *directions* of the eigenvectors. And of course you can do both.

Comment: Hii Do u know if I got minus value for my eigen vector, what I should do? Because I cannot plot it!!

Answer (score 0):

To represent each vector, use `plot3` to plot a line from the origin to the coordinates defined by the vector, perhaps multiplied by a large number (I use 10 in the example) to make the line longer:

```
plot3(10*[0 e1(1)], [0 e1(2)], [0 e1(3)],'b--');
plot3(10*[0 e2(1)], [0 e2(2)], [0 e2(3)],'g--');
```

You may need to change the view to get a good perspective. For that you can use `view` function, or click the "Rotate 3D" icon (circular arrow) in the figure toolbar.

[image]

Comment: Hii Do u know if I got minus valeu for my eigen vector, what I should do? Because I cannot plot it!!

Comment: You can plot negative as well as positive values. I don't see any problem...?

Comment: Im trying to generate the normal distribution value, so I determine the mean and variance. So I can Consider the negativ eigen vectors as positiv. For Ex: the first column of e1= [-0.0925, 0.7679, -0.6338]. I can multiply it with -1? Is that right?

Comment: @user3303896 You can multiply the eigenvector by any number and the axis will be the same. If the number is negative the axis will be reversed, but its direction will be preserved

Comment: yes, I know.. only the direction will be change. But when I try to plot it.. There is not any eigen value.. Even for e2 that 1 has 1 negative element. I use this code plot3(10*[0 e1(1)], [0 e1(2)], [0 e1(3)],'b--'); But I cannot plot the e1 & e2. Different case if I generate not normal matrixx

Comment: here is the code I use to generate the normal distributedd data...dev= 40; Mean = 0; A = dev.*randn(1000,3) + Mean;

Comment: Hiii,, why do u not answering my question?? If u know the answeer, please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use plot3

```
  a= randn(100,3); 
  b=mean(a);
  c=cov(a); 

  [vec,val] = eigs(c);

  e1=[zeros(size(vec(:,1))),vec(:,1)]'; e1 = e1/norm(e1)*4;
  e2=[zeros(size(vec(:,2))),vec(:,2)]'; e2 = e2/norm(e2)*4;
  e3=[zeros(size(vec(:,3))),vec(:,3)]'; e3 = e3/norm(e3)*4;

  plot3(a(:,1),a(:,2),a(:,3),'ro');
  hold on
  %% Here is the Problem begins
  plot3(e1(:,1),e1(:,2),e1(:,3),'k','LineWidth',2);
  plot3(e2(:,1),e2(:,2),e2(:,3),'b','LineWidth',2);
  plot3(e3(:,1),e3(:,2),e3(:,3),'g','LineWidth',2);
```

[image]

Comment: What is this mean "e1=[zeros(size(vec(:,1))),vec(:,1)]'; e1 = e1/norm(e1)*4;".. Why there is 3 lines, But in common PCA we just need 2 columns of eig vector (e1 & e2)??

Comment: Sorry @user3303896, I did not realise about that. I though it was more  clear ploting the three eignevectors as an orthogonal basis. With this line I am creating a matrix with zeros in the first row and the values of the eigenvectos in the secon row, so I can use the colums of the matrix to plot the vector with `plot3`. If you dont need the third one, you can skip the definition of `e3` and plotting it.

Comment: How about this "e1 = e1/norm(e1)*4;"

Comment: It is a rescaling, just for ploting purposes. I guess that the eigenvector already has norm equal to 1.

Comment: I meant, what is norm? Why there is 4? Why u devide e1 with norm and the multiply it with 4?